# Run CMD with UAC python

Tags: python, cmd, uac

I have the following code which asks the user for cmd elevation:

```
    ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile="C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", lpParameters=params)
    sys.exit(0)
```

The script run's the cmd as administrator and then closes the window. How can I pass arguments/commands to it before it closes ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `shell.ShellExecuteEx` function?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
As I understand, the command should be passes with the lpdirectory, but whenever I try to use: lpdirectory:"DATE 01/01/2014" it doesn't work